# How to prevent change of font family in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, python-3.7

I have written a simple code for plotting two functions - f(x) and g(x). I have a problem with my font. I have defined "Times New Roman" to be global font, but if i try to use italic style - $$, the font changes. I want the variable x in functions f(x) and g(x) to be italic and in "Times New Roman".

[Please click here for an example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGtwI.jpg)

It can bee seen that both x in f and g in legend are italic but are not in "Times New Roman" font.

This is my code, I'm using python 3.7.

```
import scipy as sy
from matplotlib import  pyplot as plt

x = sy.linspace(0, 4.188, 100)

y1 = -sy.sqrt(x) - x*sy.sqrt(x) + 0.4*x**2
y2 = - sy.exp(0.25*x) + x**0.6

plt.rcParams['font.family']='Times New Roman'

fig_1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(1.25*6.4,1.25*4.8))

chart_1 = fig_1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

chart_1.plot(x,y1, '-k', linewidth = 2, label = 'f($x$)')
chart_1.plot(x,y2, '-b', linewidth = 2, label = 'g($x$)')

chart_1.tick_params(direction='in', size=8, width=1.0, labelsize=20)

chart_1.set_xlabel('time, s', fontsize = 24)
chart_1.set_ylabel('Force, N', fontsize = 24)

chart_1.set_xlim(0,5)
chart_1.set_ylim(-4,0)

chart_1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
chart_1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')

chart_1.legend(fontsize = '20',bbox_to_anchor=(0.85,.7), edgecolor='k', borderpad = .25)

plt.show()
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text between dollar signs `$...$` is not italic, it is text that is sent to [mathtext](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) for processing.

As per the link above, mathtext has it's own rc paramters and ways to change the font used, including the use of `$\mathdefault{...}$` to match the regular text. However, if you don't want to use symbols and equations that are not possible to write in normal text, you are better off not using mathtext at all.